# Why does an array 'extend' a readonly array in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

TypeScript supports conditional types, using 'extends' keyword and ternary operators.

Example conditional types that eval to true:

```
type C1 = 7 extends number ? true : false
type C2 = 7 extends number | string ? true : false
type C3 = 7 extends 7 | 'cat' | null ? true : false
type C4 = [1,2,3] extends [1,2,3] ? true : false
type C5 = any[] extends any[] ? true : false
```

I understand the conditions above (even if 'extends' seems odd in a non-OOP context).

The following conditions I don't understand:

```
type Q1 = any[] extends readonly any[] ? true : false  // evals to true
type Q2 = readonly any[] extends any[] ? true : false  // evals to false
```

Why does Q1 evaluate to true, and Q2 evaluate to false?  I expected the opposite, as the readonly array seems 'more specific' than the general array.

What does 'extends' really mean in this context?

I am using [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) to test these conditions.

Comment: Yeah, `readonly` is kind of misleading terminology.  It would be more accurate to say `onlyKnownToBeReadableAndMayOrMayNotBeWritable`, but nobody would want to deal with that.

Answer (score 5):

`extends` means "is a subtype of". Nothing more and nothing less. And "`A` is a subtype of `B`" means "every instance of `A` is assignable to a variable of type `B`". Again, nothing more and nothing less.

So the only question we need to ask is: is a `T[]` assignable to `readonly T[]`? Well, `readonly T[]` allows us to access the elements of the array. `T[]` allows us to access the elements of an array and *also* to mutate it. So `T[]` supports all of the operations of `readonly T[]` and then some. Hence, the relationship holds.

Comment: You are correct in your wording although it might be better to say `extends` means "assignable to" because 1) it is the same terminology and behavior when assigning variables to types and 2) there are types that have weird behaviors such as `never` which is not exactly sub-type of the left hand side but still goes through the `extends` clause and `any` which gives a union of the two conditional branches.

Comment: @sno2 Good point. Updated the wording to make it a bit more clear. I'm used to more nominal languages like Scala, where it actually is a subtyping relationship. But that's not true in Typescript, strictly speaking.

Comment: @sno2 why do you say "`never` is not exactly a subtype"?  It's the bottom type in TypeScript and is therefore a subtype of every type (in the same way that the empty set is a subset of every set).

Comment: @jcalz That actually makes a lot more sense now. I had thought that it was just special handling of `never` but having it as the lowest type really makes sense when it comes to the behavior of unions eagerly reducing and intersections ignoring `never` except when it's the only thing left.

Comment: The answer doesn't make sense to me either.  Using the same concepts of readable and mutable:

// expected behavior
type A = 'readable'|'mutable' extends 'readable' ? true : false; // false
type C = 'readable' extends 'readable'|'mutable' ? true : false; // true

// backward behavior
type B = Array<any> extends ReadonlyArray<any> ? true : false; // true
type D = ReadonlyArray<any> extends Array<any> ? true : false; // false

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely confusing.

Expected behavior

```
type A = 'readable'|'mutable' extends 'readable' ? true : false; // false
type B = 'readable' extends 'readable'|'mutable' ? true : false; // true
```

The way I made any sense was to walk through assigning things.

```
const C = [1]; // inferred as Array<number>
const D:ReadonlyArray<number> = C; // declare that the mutable array is readonly
const E:Array<number> = D; // error when assigning a ReadonlyArray to Array.
```

The error seems arbitrary.  It could have been that C wasn't assignable to D.

My guess is that they went with it because of historical code in the parser.  When parsing a file with something like `const F:ReadonlyArray<number> = [1]`, [1] is probably first inferred as Array.  They needed a way to declare an already-inferred mutable array as readonly.  Hence, Array is assignable to ReadonlyArray.

That sort of makes sense, though feels like a shortcut to get around rewriting the parser.